# Move labels to the beginning of the wedge in matplotlib pie chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to move the labels from the center to the beginning of each wedge in my pie chart:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 
# Setting labels for items in Chart
Employee = ['A', 'B', 'C',
            'D', 'E']
 
# Setting size in Chart based on 
# given values
Salary = [40000, 50000, 70000, 54000, 44000]
 
# colors
colors = ['#FF0000', '#0000FF', '#FFFF00', 
          '#ADFF2F', '#FFA500']
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5), facecolor = "#FFFFFF")
# Pie Chart
wedges, texts = ax.pie(Salary, colors=colors, 
        labels=Employee, labeldistance=0.8,
        wedgeprops=dict(width=0.35),)
```

I am able to get the coordinates of the labels and replace them with:

```
for lbl,p in zip(Employee,texts, ):
        x, y = p.get_position()
        print(x,y,p)
        ax.annotate(lbl, xy=(x,y),  size=12, color = "w")
```

but I am not sure how to move them to follow the circle.

I can also get the angles of the start of each wedge calling the wedges property, but as the pie chart is drawn on a cartesian axis rather that a polar one, I am not sure how to that either?

I can not use barh for this (my chart is more complicated than the one shown here).

Is this possible?

This is where I would like the labels to be placed.

[image]

Comment: I will only put numbers so I am not worried about the length of the label. If it was text, curving it would be ideal, but not the case at the moment.
As for the position, I would like to place it in the middle and at the start of the wedge with some padding.

Comment: Note that your labels are not on the correct wedge, the blue wedge should be B

Comment: yes sorry, I photoshoped it.

Comment: Absolutely, did not know that was a thing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could compute the position of the label yourself from the properties of the wedges, adding a small angle shift (here 10°):

```
import numpy as np

wedges, texts = ax.pie(Salary, colors=colors, 
        #labels=Employee, labeldistance=0.8,
        wedgeprops=dict(width=0.35),)

shift = 10

for lbl, w in zip(Employee, wedges):
    angle = w.theta2 - shift
    r = 0.8                          # convert polar to cartesian
    x = r*np.cos(np.deg2rad(angle))  #
    y = r*np.sin(np.deg2rad(angle))  #
    ax.annotate(lbl, xy=(x,y), size=12, color='w',
                ha='center', va='center', weight='bold')
```

Output:

[image: matplotlib pie plot label annotation start of wedge]

For better visibility:

```
import matplotlib.patheffects as pe
for lbl, w in zip(Employee, wedges):
    angle = w.theta2-10
    r = 0.8
    print(lbl, angle, np.deg2rad(angle))
    x = r*np.cos(np.deg2rad(angle))
    y = r*np.sin(np.deg2rad(angle))
    ax.annotate(lbl, xy=(x,y), size=12, color='w',
                ha='center', va='center', weight='bold',
                path_effects=[pe.withStroke(linewidth=2, foreground='k')]
               )
```

[image: matplotlib pie plot label annotation start of wedge with text outline]

Comment: Thanks! I was unsure on how to do the shift, now I know :))